# Setting different heights of TabBar depending on screen size Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am using ESTabBarController to create a custom tab bar in my app. However when I set it the text is either not displaying or else it is getting covered by the Swipe up home bar. I tried using an if to check if the screen size was == to one of the screen sizes but it is still not displaying correctly.

[image]

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    // Set different tabBar height for Phone X
    var heightOffset: CGFloat = 5
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone && (UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 2436 || UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 1792 || UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 2688) {
        heightTabBar = CGFloat(60)
        heightOffset = 20
    }

    tabBar.frame = CGRect(
        origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: view.frame.size.height - heightTabBar - heightOffset),
        size: CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: heightTabBar)
    )
    
    tabBar.barTintColor = ThemeManager.viewGradientColour2
    //add line in itemBar
    bottomLineViewItemBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: tabBar.bounds.height, width: tabBar.bounds.width, height: heightOffset)
    bottomLineViewItemBar.backgroundColor = ThemeManager.viewGradientColour2
    tabBar.addSubview(bottomLineViewItemBar)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I would use `var height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height` in a different way. To assign the height of the TabBar I would use `heightTabBar = CGFloat(0.1*height)`. This means that the TabBar will be 10% of the screen height (you can change the value).

Also, you can run `safe_bottom = UIApplication.shared.windows[0].safeAreaInsets.bottom`, to avoid the letters being overlapped by the swipe up home bar. `safe_bottom` has the distance from the bottom of the screen to the part of the screen where user interacts with your UI. So, you just have to place the TabBar at a height (in pixels) of `safe_bottom` from the bottom of the screen.

Comment: The biggest issue is the text being behind the home bar. How do I apply the UIApplication.shared.windows[0].safeAreaInsets.bottom?

Comment: I think that if you use the following in your code, it should work:
heightOffset = UIApplication.shared.windows[0].safeAreaInsets.bottom. If not, also add the following:
tabBar.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:height - heightTabBar - heightOffset, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: heightTabBar). Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work, I'm not sure why the text for each of the tab bar won't move up, I added in the code you said but it is still the same where it is behind the home swipe

Comment: I checked your code again. And I think i spotted the possible problem:

bottomLineViewItemBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: tabBar.bounds.height, width: tabBar.bounds.width, height: heightOffset).

If I'm right, that bottomLineViewItemBar is the View that contains the text, right?
If so, you should set the "height" attribute to just the size of the letters. I would do something like 
bottomLineViewItemBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: tabBar.bounds.height-10, width: tabBar.bounds.width, height: 10). 

The thing is that, with the way you have it now, the bottom line view is outside the safe area.

Comment: Okay I removed that line of code however still no change. Its strange, the text just needs to go up ever so slightly but really not sure why that's not working

Comment: Hmm. Try changing the font type. I had a similar problem once, and it was a bug with the font that i was using (it moved the letters down). Also, put some background color for the Text to see where the frame is being located and facilitate the debugging.